# Get m3u8 url from website without webrowser

Tags: python, stream, m3u8

My question is straight forward.
I am trying to find the m3u8 file without opening a web browser.
The website I am using is -> https://www2.myflixer.ru/series/scorpion-l3r9m/w1rlx67
How would i get the m3u8 file in python.
The m3u8 file is not in the html
The m3u8 url of the website is -> https://ykyd.mcloud2.to/98fb9f79f5c92d3668a72325c8ec6beb29db48fd4d44c68c0b16a93b40c354594ba37caf4e5f9b5033298483641160d2ad4d19e9b780512f534eed1c5f9ae2117b6d0e14245de49ed22ab346edd94ab733bf5d0bcae92709bfcc0689f8432ec24464dfc66aee6f203115d98f6832fafb66ea4fd0e1c00d9ed5e98fd1428c4654/m/list.m3u8 the way i got it is by looking at the network while the video was streaming. I dont know how to get in python

Comment: Sounds like you want to scrape a website. Check out BeautifulSoup for Python.

Comment: No the m3u8 is not in the html, but I am not completely familiar with BeautifulSoup. Can it monitor network traffic like in the network inspector built into Chrome.

Comment: A similar question exists already, can you please try with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526739)