# How to get the URL of a m3u8 file that was returned by a HTTP request?

Tags: python, m3u8

Many websites use m3u8 files to deliver video in many short files. The m3u8 file contains the urls of all these "video pieces". When I go to the chrome devtools network tab, I can find a master.m3u8 file, but I am struggling to get the url of that file using python...

Is there a "python way", to get all the files that are returned when I visit a url?

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713238/how-to-find-m3u8-file-from-url-and-download-it) here which I don't really understand and it's also JS.

This is how my code currently looks (I have to paste the url manually which is annoying because I have to go to devtools to find it...):

```
import requests
import m3u8
import subprocess

url = str(input("Input the master.m3u8 url:\n"))

response = requests.get(url)

m3u8_master = m3u8.loads(response.text)

# usually the first playlist has the highest quality
first_playlist_path = m3u8_master.data["playlists"][0]["uri"]

link = first_playlist_path

r = requests.get(link)
playlist = m3u8.loads(r.text)

print("Downloading ts-File ... (Converting to .mp4 afterwards)")

with open("video.ts" , "wb") as f:
    for segment in playlist.data["segments"]:
        url = segment["uri"]
        r = requests.get(url)
        f.write(r.content)

ffmpeg_path = "C:/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe"
command = ["ffmpeg", '-i', 'video.ts', 'video.mp4']
subprocess.run(command)
```